# Update system time to new value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had asked same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223195/update-date-and-time-with-new-date-and-time-python?noredirect=1#) before but it was marked as duplicate. Opening a new question because only part of my question was answered.

The code in above link shows the time after adding 9 hours to current time. But I actually need to alter the system time in linux and solaris hosts.

Below is the code I used from above link, but I need to modify system time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

nine_hours_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9)
print str(datetime.now())
print str(format(nine_hours_from_now, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

After obtaining the value `nine_hours_from_now` it needs to be set as system time.

Comment: You can't do this in plain Python as it's too OS-specific

Comment: If you need to update the system time, Go to your Calender settings and update time?

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193964/set-the-hardware-clock-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40224983/3579910